# How to change the color of an link element/objects on a website with CSS ?

Tags: html, css, pdf, colors, hyperlink

The URL is www.thebusslab.com/research.html

If you go to any page and find a link or a reference to a pdf, the text will be in green. How would I go about changing the color using CSS? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You change the color of the anchor tag like this.

```
a {
    color: green;
}
```

You can try to only target pdf links like this. This will target all anchor tags that have a `href` attribute ending in `.pdf`.

```
a[href$='.pdf'] {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your main.css file you have a rule:

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #8BC53F;
}
```

which drives this. Set the colour hex to any colour you like.

Answer (score 0):

All type of links(normal, visited,...) need to be styled:

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being set in your file main.css

```
a {
    color: #8bc53f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can learn about styling links here
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        a[href$='.html'] {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="test.html">This is some text in a paragraph.</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Run this code and you will get the idea how to do it.

Comment: While this code-only post might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so.